# able to hit get method endpoint but unable to hit POST method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

following is my code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value ="/registration",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserDTO userDTO) {
        System.out.println("from Post");
        userService.saveUser(userDTO);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard/getUserDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<UserDTO> getUsers() {
        System.out.println("inside controller");
        return userService.getUsers();
    }}
```

in the above code when i am trying to hit get endpoint its working and when i am trying to hit POST endpoint it is throwing 404.

please help me in solving the problem

Comment: maybe some param is missing on your url? are you providing a body with the userDTO? are you really doing an POST or just navigating to the URL on your browser?

Comment: i am trying access it through postman

Comment: really doing a post operation.......

Comment: please add more code: UserDto, request (curl with httpmethod and parameters)